# bash - как выполнить команду после того как скрипт открывает стороннюю программу?

Tags: bash, консоль, devops

Открываем файл в программе

```
"$ide" 'scss/app.scss'
```

и скрипт зависает до закрытия программы. Как запустить эту команду после предыдущей строчки в скрипте?

```
npm start
```

Comment: Запустите в фоне - `"$ide" 'scss/app.scss'  &`.

Comment: @0xdb, спасибо за быстрый ответ

Comment: Рад  был помочь!

Answer (score 0):

Завершите комманду символом `&`. Из `man bash`:

> If  a  command  is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command in the background in a subshell. **The shell does not wait for the
>          command to finish**, and the return status is 0.

```sh
$ bash -c "
{ sleep 1; echo longplayer; }&
echo nextcommand
"
nextcommand
longplayer
```